# Convert variable with custom value into date time format in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a variable with values of form "`(31-Aug-2010) 14:00:41.386`"  how can i convert it into Date time format in R.

I did try:

```
as.POSIXct(Date.Time,format="(%d-%m-%Y) %H:%M:%OS3")

my_date = strptime(as.character(Date.Time),"(%d-%m-%Y) %H:%M:%OS3")

library(lubridate)
mdy_hms(Date.Time,format= "(%d-%m-%Y) %H:%M:%OS3")
```

None of them worked for me.All the above methods gave NA's with warning message "All formats failed to parse.No formats found."
Can anyone suggest me better way.
I did try looking at answers for other similar questions on this website but couldn't find suitable answer,so posted a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the month is in three letter format, in the `format`, it should be `%b` and not `%m`.  It is well documented in [strptime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)

```
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "(%d-%b-%Y) %H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2010-08-31 14:00:41 IST"
```

If we change the `options`, it will print the milliseconds

```
op <- options(digits.secs=3)
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "(%d-%b-%Y) %H:%M:%OS")
#[1] "2010-08-31 14:00:41.385 IST"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "(31-Aug-2010) 14:00:41.386"
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, but he used `%OS3`

Comment: So this is the answer. Not *"format"*. Also the `%b` part. Also, explaining why `%OS` should be used instead of  `%OS3` could be useful

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right, I didn't see the first `format`, .

Comment: Thanks Akrun for the answer, what does OS3 and OS do? I thought OS3 gives milliseconds for 3 decimals

Comment: @alily For some reason `OSN` is not working in `R 3.3.0` and instead you can print all the milliseconds with just OS after setting the `options`